# Connectedness and compactness of K-topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $T_K$ be the K-topology on $\mathbb{R}$, this is, the topology generated by the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$ and the sets of the form $(a,b)-K$, with $K=\{1/n, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$.

How do you prove that $T_K$ is **connected** and that it is **not compact**?

Not compact should follow from the fact that the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, but how exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For compactness, note that the $K$ topology on the reals is finer than the standard one (that is, any open subset of $\mathbb R$ is also open in $T_K$). So any open cover for $\mathbb R$ in the usual topology is also an open cover for $T_K$.

For connectedness, it might be helpful to show that $T_K-\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R - \{0\}$ (both considered with the subspace topologies), via the identity set map. Given this,

$$T_K^{+}:=\{x \in T_K: x>0\}$$ and $$T_K^-:=\{x \in T_K: x<0\}$$ are both connected in the subspace topology. Suppose that $T_k = A \cup B$, for $A,B$ nonempty open with $A \cap B = \emptyset.$ Then $$T_K^+ = (A\cap T_K^+) \cup (B\cap T_K^+),$$ which implies $T_K^+ \subset A$ or $T_K^+ \subset B$. A similar argument shows $T_K^{-} \subset A$ or $T_K^{-} \subset B$. This forces that either $A=(0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty,0]$; or $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty, 0)$. In each case you can verify that either $A$ or $B$ is not open in $T_K$.

Comment: Thanks, I've read $(a,b)-K$ with $K\in \{\dfrac{1}{n}, n\in \Bbb Z^+\}$.